# Mongoose save with promises and populate

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, promise, bluebird

I have the following code (Mongoose has been promisified with Bluebird)

```
function createNewCourse(courseInfo, teacherName) {
    var newCourse = new courseModel({
        cn: courseInfo.courseName,
        cid: courseInfo.courseId
    });

    return newCourse.saveAsync()
        .then(function (savedCourse) {
            var newTeacher = new newTeacherModel({
                na: teacherName,
                _co: savedCourse._id // This would be an array
            });

            return newTeacher.saveAsync().then(function() {
                return newCourse;
            });
        });
}
```

This is a simplification of my problem, but it illustrates it well. I want my createNewCourse function to return a promise that, once resolved, will return the newly saved course, *not* the teacher. The above code works, but it's not elegant and does not use promises well to avoid callback hell.

Another option I considered is returning the course and then doing a populate, but that would mean re-querying the database.

Any ideas how to simplify this?

**Edit**: I thought it might be useful to post the save code but using native callbacks (omitting error-handling)

```
function createNewCourse(courseInfo, teacherName, callback) {
    var newCourse = new courseModel({
        cn: courseInfo.courseName,
        cid: courseInfo.courseId
    });

    newCourse.save(function(err, savedCourse) {
        var newTeacher = new newTeacherModel({
            na: teacherName,
            _co: savedCourse._id // This would be an array
        });

        newTeacher.save(function(err, savedTeacher) {
            callback(null, newCourse);
        });
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`.return()`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#returndynamic-value---promise):

```
function createNewCourse(courseInfo, teacherName) {
    var newCourse = new courseModel({
        cn: courseInfo.courseName,
        cid: courseInfo.courseId
    });

    return newCourse.saveAsync().then(function (savedCourse) {
        var newTeacher = new newTeacherModel({
            na: teacherName,
            _co: savedCourse._id // This would be an array
        });

        return newTeacher.saveAsync();
    }).return(newCourse);
}
```

Remember how chaining works?

```
.then(function() {
    return somethingAsync().then(function(val) {
        ...
    })
})
```

Is equivalent to (disregarding any closure variables):

```
.then(function() {
    return somethingAsync()
})
.then(function(val) {
    ...
})
```

`return(x)` is simply equivalent to `.then(function(){return x;})`